# Conditions of the Alternating series test

Tags: calculus

In the Alternating series test, if the following conditions hold

1. $a_n> 0$ for each $n$
2. $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$
3. $a_n>a_{n+1}$ for each $n\geq n_0$, where $n_0$ is some constant.

then the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^na_n$ converges.

Is there exist a converges series of the form $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^na_n$ such that (1) and (2) hold but not (3)? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**. One may consider
$$
a_n:=\frac1{n+1+(-1)^n},\quad n\ge1.
$$

Comment: @boaz You are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a_n=\frac{\sin^2(n)}{n}$.

We can write $a_n=\frac{1+\cos(2n)}{2n}$ and inasmuch as both $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{2n}$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n\cos(2n)}{2n}$ converge, their sum does likewise.

But $a_{n+1}<a_n$ does not hold in general.

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can. -Mark

Answer (score 1):

Pick any positive convergent series $\sum b_n$. Then, for each permutation $\sigma : \mathbb N \to \mathbb N$ the series 
$$\sum_n (-1)^n b_{\sigma(n)}$$
is absolutely convergent thus convergent.

It then satisfies the conditions (1) and (2) but it is easy to come with permutations so that $3$ fails.

A simple such example is $a_{2n}=\frac{1}{(2n+1)^2}$ and $a_{2n+1}=\frac{1}{(2n)^2}$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, let $a_1=1/2$ and $a_n=1/(n-1)$ for $n\geq 2$.

Comment: your right, I missed that trivial cases. I will edit my question.